# Can you pass props to a JSX reference?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-props

*Before I begin with my question, allow me to clarify - the question here is a simplification of the issue, I'm working on an already large codebase on a legacy project for a client on short timespan and re-structuring the data would take me more time than trying to figure this out - I know this is not an ideal way to be try to be passing props around, so please don't just link to tutorial about how to be passing props*

The gist of it is, I have a large array of objects, all of which have the following property `{ icon: <SomeJSXReference /> }`
I basically created a re-usable abstraction component that returns the icon property based on certain passed props into it.

Issue is, i need to pass one of the props to the `icon` reference itself.
Here's a rough pseudo-component I've written, to make it a bit clearer.

```
const objectsArray = [{ icon: <SpecificIcon /> }, /*...*/]
const Simplified = (props: { color: string }) => {
  const { color } = props
  const toRender = objectsArray.someOperationsLeadingToFinalObjectReference()
  return toRender.icon
}
```

**What I need to do is somehow append a `stroke={color}` prop to the JSX referenced inside the `toRender.icon` pointer**

Resulting basically in

- `<toRender.icon stroke={color} />` *(toRender as pseudo-pointer, note the lowercase)*
- `<SpecificIcon stroke={color} />` *(equivalent of above = what should be returned) ˆ*

*Note: This does not explicitly have to be `<SpecificIcon />`, but rather whatever JSX.Element `toRender.icon` points to*

Is there any way I could do this, that's not occuring to me?

Comment: if `toRender.icon` is a component, return <ToRender.Icon stroke={color}/> should work... notice the case  `toRender.item` vs `ToRender.Icon`

Comment: issue is, I don't know what the resulting `toRender.icon` will be. Basically I need `<SpecificIcon stroke={color} />`. So I can't just manually type it out. `<ToRender.icon />` is just a non-existing element that's not defined. Unless Im somehow misunderstanding you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways you can do it.

1. If the component already constructed (for what constructed means see [JSX in Depth](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html)):

```
{ icon: <SpecificIcon /> }
```

You can use `React.cloneElement`:

```
[<Counter />].map(Component => React.cloneElement(Component, { num: 5 }))
```

2. If the component not constructed (which is **a better approach**, because the function/constructor doesn't yet executed):

```
{ icon: SpecificIcon }
```

You can render it while passing props:

```
[Counter].map((Component, index) => <Component key={index} num={2} />)
```

---

See full example:

```
const Counter = ({ num = 0 }) => <div>{num}</div>;

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Counter />
      {[<Counter />].map(Component =>
        React.cloneElement(Component, { num: 4 })
      )}
      {[Counter].map((Component, index) => (
        <Counter key={index} num={2} />
      ))}
    </>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit busy-zhukovsky-wxjhw]

Comment: Hey @DennisVash , thanks for the awesome answer. Just one small detail, shouldn't the second variant in your full example say `<Component key={index} num={2} />` instead? If you could have referenced `<Counter />` straight away it kinda defeats the entire purpose, obviously it will work in your example since it's declared in the same file, but that's not the case for the specific issue.

Comment: At the very bottom of your post, in your full example, you map the counter reference and inside the function argument you extract Component, however you end up returning the constructed `<Counter />` rather than the extracted `<Component />`.  Am I making sense here, or still unclear?

Comment: To show that it is dynamic, for if it was `[Counter,Icon,Something]`, the name doesn't matter, you can reference it as `CoolComponent` for example

Comment: I guess, but that would only work when you would always be returning specifically `Counter`. The very purpose of the question is, that you might not always be returning it, hence you don't always wanna be constructing explicitly `Counter`, but rather whatever reference the `toRender.icon` points to. To put it in simpler terms, you always return in the end the same component, meanwhile in my case what gets returned varies. Either way, doesn't really matter, found a way to adapt it to fit my purpose :-)

Comment: You have no problem to check which component it is `Component.displayName`, and you also can pass generic props `<Component {...props}/>`, and yes you are right I get your point now :-)

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I did in my case. I guess it's partially my fault for only providing a vague pseudo-example :-)